# How to prove that the mutual information is subadditive?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, information-theory, entropy, probability, mutual-information

Let $\mathbf x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $\mathbf y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ be two vectors of random variables. To make things concrete, assume that Alice sends each component $x_j$ through a noisy channel to Bob, who then receives the output $y_j$. The conditional probability to obtain $\mathbf x$ given $\mathbf y$ is $$p(\mathbf y|\mathbf x)=\prod_{j=1}^np_j(y_j|x_j), $$ and for each probability $p_j(y_j|x_j)$ we may define the mutual information $I_j(x_j:y_j)$. I should prove that $$I(\mathbf x:\mathbf y)\le \sum_{j=1}^n I_j(x_j:y_j), $$ that is, the mutual information is subadditive. What is the simplest way to go about this?

Comment: Are you certain that what you are trying to prove is actually provable or are you trying out a new proof?

Comment: @QuestionEverything In all honesty, this was given as an exercise in my course, so I hope my professor wasn't trolling us :-)

Comment: I see, :) I haven't seen this proof before.

Comment: What is quantum about this? It seems to be a question about classical information theory.

Comment: @DaftWullie Yes, it is. I hope it's not off-topic for the site... I'm posting here by default as all this was done in a course in quantum information theory. After all, the tag `information-theory` is also dedicated to 'information theory in the classical sense'.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike entropy, mutual information can be either subadditive or superadditive.

1. If $A$, $B$, $C$ are
   bits with equal probabilities and $A=B=C$, then
   $$
     I(A,B:C) = 1,\\
     I(A:C) + I(B:C) =  2,
     $$ therefore $I(A,B:C) < I(A:C) + I(B:C)$.
2. On the other hand, if $A$, $B$, $C$ are bits with equal probabilities and $A \oplus B \oplus C = 0$ ($\oplus$ is XOR), then
   $$
       I(A,B:C) = 1,\\
       I(A:C) + I(B:C) = 0,
     $$     therefore $I(A,B: C) > I(A:C) + I(B:C)$.

[source](https://cs-people.bu.edu/mbun/courses/591_F19/notes/lec6.pdf) (pg.4)